# Maven: pom equivalent of "cvf <inputfile>" command?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am new to maven so bear with me. Right now I have a folder that I compile into a jar with the following command:

`cvf fonts.jar net report_properties.properties`

I more or less copied this folder into another project that's using maven, and I'm wondering if there's a way to set up the pom.xml such that I end up compiling the same jar except with maven (namely with the `mvn clean install` command)?

So far I've tried using the resource and includes tags in a pom.xml I added to the root of that folder like so:

```
....
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>./</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/report_properties.properties</include>
                <include>**/net</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
....
```

But no luck (I tried with just `net` and `report_properties.properties` instead of `**/report_properties`, `**_net` as well). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The best way for `Maven` is using [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

So you should put jour source code `*.java` files in `src/main/java` and resources like `report_properties.properties` in `src/main/resources`.

Then you don't need special configurations for `sourceDirectory` and `resources`